# Add lists in a certain range

Tags: python, list

Given two lists in Python, how can I add `k` consecutive elements of the first list to `k` consecutive elements of the second list, starting from an arbitrary index? The index that marks the start of the respective `k` block of elements can differ from list 1 to list 2.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

l2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 

new_l2 = [1, 1, 2+1, 3+1, 4+1, 5+1]
```

In this example I want to add the second to fifth (`k == 4`) elements from `l1` to the last `k == 4` elements of `l2`. I want the changes to be reflected in `l2`

The goal is for the program to execute as fast as possible (e.g maps or list comprehension).

Comment: So where is your attempt, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: You want the changes to be reflected in `l2`?  That's now what your "example" implies.  It implies that you want a new `l2` which is different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are already using Numpy I would suggest you to use in-place splice assignment functionality along with a bit of functional map and zip just like some existing answers

**Implementation**

```
def foo(l1, l2, i, j, k):
    #from itertools import izip
    l2[j:j + k] = map(sum, zip(l1[i: i +k], l2[j: j + k]))
    #l2[j:j + k] = map(sum, izip(l1[i: i +k], l2[j: j + k]))
    return l2
```

In the above function

- i - Start index of first list
- j - Start index of second list
- l1, l2 - Individual Lists
- k - length of change

**Example**

```
foo(l1, l2, 1, 2, 4)
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
def addlists(l1, l2, k):
     return [l1[i]+l2[i] if i >= k else l2[i] for i in range(len(l2))]
```

As such:

```
>>> addlists(l1, l2, 2)
[1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> addlists(l1, l2, 4)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 7]
```

Comment: That is what i'm doing `if i >= k`

Comment: My mistake, I see what you are doing now

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_from(l1, l2, start):
    return l2[:start] + [i + j for i,j in zip(l1[start:], l2[start:])]

>>> add_from(l1, l2, 2)
[1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to work with numpy instead of python lists, you'll likely see speedups for this sort of operation -- plus the code ends up being cleaner.  This code becomes:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
a2 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])  # np.ones(len(a1), dtype=int)) might be faster.
a2[-4:] += a1[2:6]
print(a2)  # array([1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly understood the specification, this would do it:

```
def weird_add(l1, l2, i1, i2, k):
    """Add k elements from l1, starting at i1, to l2, starting at i2."""
    for ind1, ind2 in zip(range(i1, i1+k), range(i2, i2+k)):
        l2[ind2] = l2[ind2] + l1[ind1]
```

In use:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> weird_add(l1, l2, 1, -4, 4)
>>> l2
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and `sum` for adding in a `list comprehension`

```
def add_list(l1, l2, k):
    return l2[:k] + [sum(i) for i in zip(l1[k:], l2[k:])]
>>>print add_list(l1, l2, 3)
[1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 7]
```